# Radius of convergence: Why do we always use nth root test or ratio test?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis

Is this just definitional? I never did this in calculus but in complex analysis we defined the radius of convergence by the limit supremum of the nth root of the terms of a series. Why does this definition give you the "the largest disk in which the series converges?" Does this have to do with these tests telling you series that converge geometrically, or really fast?

Comment: the test that everybody uses is $|a_n| < C R^{-n}$ and for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is no $cste$ such that $|a_n| < cste \ (R+\epsilon)^{-n}$ hence the radius of convergence of $\sum_n a_n z^n$ is $R$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my view it is not really the definition of the radius of convergence.

Rather the definition of the radius of convergence of 
$$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n(z - c)^n $$ is 
$R=\sup\{|z_0 - c | \colon \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n(z_0 - c)^n \text{ converges}\}$.

With this definition, it is clear that this is the largest disk where the convergence could possibly happen; one still has to show that indeed 
$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n(z - c)^n$ converges *for every* $z$ with $|z-c|< R$.

One can then further show that the radius of convergence is in fact equal to the reciprocal of $\lim\sup\{\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}\}$. Thus, one could also take this as definition. But I would not do so. Rather it is a way to determine the radius of convergence, defined as above.