# Hadamard's theorem; redefining indexing variable

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

I have seen in a few proofs the use of Hadamard's theorem to prove convergence of series like this:

$\sum_{n\geq 0}z^{n!}$, or $\sum_{n\geq 0}z^{n^2}$ through simply changing the variable of indexing to $m=n!$ or $m=n^2$ and taking the $m$'th root of the limit supremum to find explicitly the radius of convergence.

Obviously it works in these cases, but is not clear to me how to justify that it gives you the radius of convergence. My class only defined the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum_{n\geq 0}a_nz^{n}$ as 
$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sup|a_n|^{1/n}=R^{-1}$

Comment: it is $\lim \sup_{n \to \infty} |a_n|^{1/n}$. and the radius of convergence is the $R$ such that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $C$ such that $|a_n| <  C|R-\epsilon|^{-n}$, but there is no such $C$ anymore when $\epsilon < 0$

Comment: sorry, even fixing that typo I don't see how this answers my question? Here, I can add what I am trying to show above.

Comment: it is obvious : $\sum_{n=0}^\infty  z^n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{n^2}$ have the same radius of convergence.

Comment: i try not to assert things are obvious at this stage, but ok

Comment: it is obvious once you understood that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty R^{-n} z^n$ has a radius of convergence $R$ !!! because for $|z| < R$ it converges, for $|z| > R$ it diverges !!! come on. that's why I said : forget about the $|a_n|^{1/n}$, just ask : when does it converge, when does it diverge

Comment: ohhhhh you're the guy who totally misunderstood my question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1763432/radius-of-convergence-why-do-we-always-use-nth-root-test-or-ratio-test      And to the think I allowed you to make me feel bad for a second! edit: you edited away your condescension, so this looks weird now